# How to display html in only the first level of WP comments?

Tags: comments, functions

How would I display html code in only the first level of threaded comments?

*Example*
L1 Comment
----L2 Comment
--------L3 Comment
L1 Comment

I have a piece of html code that contains basically reads "Reply to (author name) or post a new comment" and only need it displayed on L1 comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the comments loop:

```
if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { //if the comment does not have a parent, then it is L1
    echo 'my-custom-html';
}
```